# Better way for users to select a range in a table like structure

Tags: tables, selection, checkboxes, sliders, range

I am struggling to find the best UI for contiguous row selection. 
Each row comprises of a start time, text and an end time.

Do you think click and SHIFT + click is still a valuable option for non IT users in 2016?

I have also tried a checkbox on the left + start time, and one checkbox on the right + end time (for each row). This seems a good solution but takes too much horizontal space.

```
[x] 00:00 | a sentence             | 00:10 [ ] 
[ ] 00:10 | another sentence       | 00:15 [ ] 
[ ] 00:15 | a sentence blah        | 00:23 [x] 
[ ] 00:23 | another one....        | 00:40 [ ]
```

Bear in mind that the table is scrollable, thus for example I can hardly see a drag and drop vertical slider as an option because of this fact (but correct me if I am wrong).

Any idea is welcome here.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @agori! Is there a reason the selection needs to take place in the table itself? (Is it possible to use a control near the table to select a timespan?)

Answer (score 1):

1. Avoid shift + click. Only IT Crowds will think to try this.
2. You said "contiguous" row selection.  If that is the case I suggest you offer a "selection mode" command. When entering this mode, the user will select the first row, scroll and then select the last row.  You can provide a command to "reset" their selection, and for bonus points even guide them through the process based on the current state of the selection e.g. "Total duration selected: 2min 10sec".